# Unhandled exception at 0x775615de in ValedasFloresRetail.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c, pointers, access-violation

> Unhandled exception at 0x775615de in ValedasFloresRetail.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

I'm getting this error and i've no clue on whats happening

```
pProduto **iniciaDados(int *corredores, int *armarios){

pProduto **Armazem=NULL;
FILE *f;
int i,j,k;
int id,quantidade;
int numProdutos;
pProduto novo;

f=fopen("retailA.bin","rb");

if(f==NULL){
    printf("Erro na leitura\n");
    return NULL;
}

fread(corredores,sizeof(int),1,f);
fread(armarios,sizeof(int),1,f);

novo=(pProduto)malloc(sizeof(produto));

for(i=0;i<*corredores;i++){
    Armazem[i]=(pProduto *)malloc(sizeof(pProduto)*(*armarios));
}

for(i=0;i<*corredores;i++)
    for(j=0;j<*armarios;j++){
        Armazem[i][j]=NULL;
    }

for(i=0;i<*corredores;i++){
    for(j=0;j<*armarios;j++){
        fread(&numProdutos,sizeof(int),1,f);
        for(k=0;k<numProdutos;k++){
            fread(&id,sizeof(int),1,f);
            fread(&quantidade,sizeof(int),1,f);
            Armazem[i][j]=adicionaProduto(Armazem[i][j],id,quantidade);

        }
    }
}

return Armazem;
}
```

When I go to the call stack, it says that the error is here: `pProduto **Armazem=NULL;` and it shows this:

> CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: It looks like `Armazem`'s first dimension is never allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating through :

```
for(i=0;i<*corredores;i++){
    Armazem[i]=(pProduto *)malloc(sizeof(pProduto)*(*armarios));
}
```

Such that each cell of `Armazem` has a size, but not Armazem itself. You should have a line looking like this first :

```
Armazem = (pProduto **)malloc((*corredores)*sizeof(pProduto*));
```

at the beginning of your code.

Otherwise `Armazem` remain NULL, as mentionned by the error message.